# React Native Deep Linking - Broken?

Tags: react-native

I'm using React-Native, and have react native navigation 5.0

I've tried looking all over and compared different fixes but:

1. Android dosen't seem to recognize xx:// paths as links on neither chrome, messages, or other apps (like whatsapp). The only way i could get it to actually work on the 
   actual device is by making the deeplink with https://xx.com. I have no problems with doing xx:// on CLI - but who cares about CLI when the actual device dosen't work. For example, you can try to see if you can open fb:// on your android device (facebook).
2. IOS seems to only work with xx:// and not https://xx.com because https: seems to be reserved for safari.

Does that mean that i'm forced to do universal links via the Browser way?

What is everyone else doing?

Answer (score 0):

Decided to just do universal linking